# Get random line from CSV file in Python and find corresponding word, like a quiz

Tags: python, csv

Sorry for the ambiguous title. Couldn't think of a better way to word it.

I have a CSV file of German/English words like so:

```
Ja,Yes
Nein,No
Katze,Cat
```

I want my python script to print a random German word from the CSV file and ask for them to type in the English word. When the do so and hit return, it should print correct or false.

I kind of have some outline for the code:

```
loop = 1
choice = 0

while loop == 1:
    randWord = choice(de)

    correctAnswer = ? 

    answer = raw_input("Answer: ")

    if answer == correctAnswer:
        print ("Correct")
        print ("")
    elif answer == "exit":
        loop = 0
    elif answer != correctAnswer:
        print ("False")
        print ("The correct answer was ") + correctAnswer
        print ("Let's try another.")
        print ("")
```

My problem is two fold:

1) Selecting the random row and word from the CSV file.
2) Matching the randomly selected word from the CSV file to its German counterpart.

Any ideas on how I might go about both of these?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like the perfect choice for the Python `dictionary` data structure. Read the csv file into one, generate a random key into the dictionary to give you the word (your key) and then compare the user's answer against the associated value (given your key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import csv
import random

words = dict(csv.reader(open("file.csv")))
randWord = random.choice(words.keys())
correctAnswer = words[randWord]

if answer == correctAnswer:
    ...
```

**edit:** I should note that you should convert `words.keys()` to a list first if you're using Python 3, as `dict.keys()` returns a list in Python 2.x, but a generator in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I am using Python 2.x. Although, I used the exact code you posted there, with correct file and my code in place of the ... but I am getting the error `File "germanvocab.py", line 7, in <genexpr> words = dict( (de, en) for (de, en) in csv.reader("Words.csv"))`. Do you know what this could be? Thank you.

Comment: `words = dict(csv.reader(open("file.csv")))` should be sufficient.

Comment: @samiles, I just forgot to put a file handle instead of a string. My apoligies. And Tim, I added your change.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = [line for line in f]
    ger, correctAnswer = random.choice(lines).split(',')
```

And I think you can take it from here :-)

Comment: This approaches leaves the endline characters in correctAnswer.

Comment: Also, it doesn't handle certain CSV formatting options like quotation marks and such. The `csv` module is a much better way to handle csv files.